# Copy path to variable in array using Kint

Tags: 8, debugging

In D7 using `dmp()` with Krumo in produced output like this:

[image]

Double clicking on a variable value, in this case "foobar" shows the path through the array to that value (the highlighted text in the image above).

Now with D8 it's using Kint not Krumo and produces output like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to copy the path to "foobar" using kint?

This is the text that I want: `['example']['#attributes']['class'][0]`

Comment: Great question. Right now there is no way that I know of, I ran into the same issue. I used to copy the path in D7 with Search Krumo but as far as I can tell, there is no equivalent in D8 with Kint. This might be a good feature request for the Devel module but it definitely slows down development time in D8.

Comment: Consider using xdebug instead. Since I've started debugging with xdebug & phpstorm I haven't looked back at DPM even once.

Comment: Yeah - I do get xdebug out when the debugging gets really heavy but I also love a quick bit of `dpm`. Search krumo is an awesome module. Maybe I should just write search kint!?!

Comment: @Eyal - Can you point us to a good tutorial on getting started with xdebug/phpstorm (with remote Drupal server if possible) ?

Comment: @NicCottrell look for the tutorials on phpstorm and xdebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seemed there was no solution so I just copied the search_krumo module and changed it a bit so it works with Drupal 8 and kint and made [search_kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_kint).

I've only just done the first push so isn't showing as a download yet; and there is only a development snapshot release, at the moment, but it's something to get started with.

So far, it has worked well with my testing.

EDIT: search_kint now has a full release.

Comment: wow, fantastic, can't wait to try it!